# Compare a string to escape characters

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to compare a string against a string containing escape characters.

What I have to far is:

```
var text = '\\SPX\FTP';
if(text.substring(0,2) === '\\'){
    console.info('true')
}
```

This should be true but isn't.

Comment: why should it be true?

Comment: The actual value if `text` is `\SPXFTP` is that correct?

Comment: The actual value of `text` is `\\SPX\FTP`

Comment: `alert("\\SPX\FTP")` would be `\SPXFTP`

Comment: If I write out `text` in a the console it returns `\\SPX\FTP`

Comment: Then whatever console your using is being friendly and adding the escapes back in for you to see. https://jsfiddle.net/alexk/1ur53wmf/

Comment: try `console.info('string : ', text)` that's what I did in `Chrome` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the `\` is escaped, you need to compare to one character only:

```
var text = '\\SPX\FTP';
if(text.substring(0,1) === '\\'){
    console.info('true')
}
```

Comment: Will that not compare the string \ rather than \\ ?

Comment: I ended up comparing to `if(text.substring(0,2) === '\\\\')` which worked

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings) in ES6, or are transpiling using Babel, you can use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```
var text = String.raw`\\SPX\FTP`;
if(text.substring(0,2) === String.raw`\\`){
    console.info('true')
}
```

Returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Either compare to one character or two, depending on what you require.

One (I suspect this is the one you'll need):

```
var text = '\\SPX\FTP';
if (text.substring(0, 1) === '\\') { // Remember \\ after escape == \
    console.info('true')
}
```

Two:

```
var text = '\\SPX\FTP';
if (text.substring(0, 2) === '\\S') {
    console.info('true')
}
```